# Singleton example in C++/CLI?

Tags: singleton, c++-cli

I've looked around, I need an example for Singleton class that works across 2 or more C++/CLI files.

How do you declare a singleton in C++/CLI, not C# ?

How do you share that singleton across two or more C++/CLI files?

I keep getting Variable redefinitions when I try to share that singleton.

Comment: You will have to be more specific.  Does it need lazy initialization?  Does it need to be thread safe?  Is disposal required?

Comment: Any example... there is none for C++.NET singleton. I get Redefinition errors, Needs to be managed, but the class is already byref, I get needs ";" before "}", I also get needs ":" after variable.

Comment: I'll give this question a week or so. If there are no answers, I'll place a bounty on this question... This is almost impossible question with 0 solution(s) available on the Internet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is for C++/CLI, not ".NET Managed Extensions for C++" aka C++.NET.  Don't use the Managed Extensions (Visual Studio 2002-2003), they're buggy.

```
ref class Singleton
{
private:
  Singleton() {}
  Singleton(const Singleton%) { throw gcnew System::InvalidOperationException("singleton cannot be copy-constructed"); }
  static Singleton m_instance;

 public:
  static property Singleton^ Instance { Singleton^ get() { return %m_instance; } }
};
```

As for "across multiple files", other compilation units in the same project use `#include`, other assemblies use a reference (or `#import`).  Then there won't be any redefinition issues.

Comment: And how do you call this?

Answer (score 0):

These may be useful

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188779.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817670(pandp.10).aspx

Comment: These do not work with C++.NET. they work only either on C++ or C#.NET